# Kendo Grid, not populating Data from a Database properly, when using IE8

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've been attempting get a Kendo grid to properly populate inside of an IE8(The people using the program are stuck on Windows XP). It works perfectly fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the Code that I am using.

My cshtml File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@model IEnumerable<SymPro.ViewModels.InvestViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Accounts";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<font size ="1">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SymPro.ViewModels.InvestViewModel>()
                                    .Name("gridInvest")
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.asset_num).Title("Invest. <br/> No.");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.cusipnum).Title("Security <br/> ID").Width(80);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.rempar).Title("Remaining <br/> Par").Format("{0:0.00}").Width(100);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.issuer).Title("Issuer");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.purdate).Title("Purchased").Width(100);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.maturdate).Title("Mature/Sell").Width(100);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.invtype).Title("Type");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.fund_num).Title("Fund");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.nomrate).Title("Rate").Format("{0:0.00}");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.facevalue).Title("Par <br/> Value").Format("{0:0.00}");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.groupcd).Title("Group");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.sectorcd).Title("Sector");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.identity_column).Title("")
                                            .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = "#= identity_column#" }, new { style = "color:blue" })
                                            .ToHtmlString()
                                            );
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.identity_column).Title("")
                                            .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "#= identity_column#" }, new { style = "color:blue" })
                                            .ToHtmlString()
                                            );
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.identity_column).Title("")
                                            .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = "#= identity_column#" }, new { style = "color:blue" })
                                            .ToHtmlString()
                                            );
                                    })                                    
                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("Invest_Read", "Invest"))                                        
                                    )
                                    .Sortable()
                                    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(450))                   

                                )
    </font>
```

My Invest_Read Action result

```
public ActionResult Invest_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            decimal initzero = 0000000000000.00M;
            string initcode = "";
            string DefPublCd = "";

            var dbAgencyQuery = (from d in db.dbagency
                                 select d).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dbAgencyQuery != null)
            {
                DefPublCd = dbAgencyQuery.defpublcd;
            }

            DateTime general = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            DateTime? empty = null;

            var accounts = (from i in db.invest
                            join s in db.dbsumcalcs on i.asset_num equals s.asset_num into i_s
                            from subi_s in i_s.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join f in db.fisectasgn on i.ficspkey equals f.cspkey into i_f
                            from subi_f in i_f.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join e in db.sector on subi_f.syseckey equals e.syseckey into f_e
                            from subf_e in f_e.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where subf_e.publcd == DefPublCd
                            orderby i.maturdate
                            select new InvestViewModel
                            {
                                asset_num = i.asset_num,
                                cusipnum = i.cusipnum,
                                rempar = (subi_s == null ? initzero : subi_s.rempar),
                                issuer = i.issuer,
                                purdate = (i.maturdate == general || i.maturdate == DateTime.MinValue ? empty : i.purdate),
                                maturdate = (i.maturdate == general || i.maturdate == DateTime.MinValue ? empty : i.maturdate),
                                invtype = i.invtype,
                                fund_num = i.fund_num,
                                nomrate = i.nomrate,
                                facevalue = i.facevalue,
                                creditcode = (subi_s == null ? initcode : subi_s.creditcode),
                                credrte2 = (subi_s == null ? initcode : subi_s.credrte2),
                                groupcd = (subf_e == null ? initcode : subf_e.groupcd),
                                sectorcd = (subf_e == null ? initcode : subf_e.sectorcd),
                                identity_column = i.identity_column
                            });

            DataSourceResult result = accounts.ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Don't you need some <html> etc. tags? I don't know if that would help with your problem, but it would make me feel happier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. In my View Model InvestViewModel I had a variable named @class which was being used elsewhere in the program, however that was causing an issue in Kendo when it was being passed to the grid, even though it was Null.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have followed the instruction from the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#downloading-and-installing-kendo-ui-complete-for-asp.net-mvc) added the kendo.aspnetmvc.js file to your layout page. Also the [troubleshooting](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting) might come in handy.

Comment: That File is located inside of my _layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect html generated using browser developer tools. I think IE8 doesnt support html5 and kendo grid might be using custom attributes like data-xxxx.

Comment: I know it's working as I am using Kendo grid with other pages on the application and those are working as intended.